# Is there a way to set ask-password 0 as the default when opening up any monero wallet file?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, refresh

I have a bunch of wallet files and when I do a refresh via the command line, it hits me with the password. I can set ask-password to 0, but is there a global setting that I can put somewhere for all future wallet files I create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Spam for stupid length check.